# "Улепетывать" и "лепетать": родственные ли слова?

Tags: однокоренные-слова

По смыслу в словах "улепетывать" (удирать, убегать) и "лепетать" нет ничего общего. Тем не менее, у них общий корень "-лепет-" (если я не ошибаюсь). Действительно ли эти слова однокоренные и что их связывает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашла кое-что по поводу.Улепетывать улепетну́ть. Производят от лепета́ть (Преобр. I, 447 и сл.), что не объясняет знач. ("удаляться с лепетом"?!). Затруднительно и сближение с ла́па (Горяев, ЭС 387). Этимологический словарь русского языка. — М.: Прогресс М. Р. Фасмер 1964—1973

Answer (score 2):

На Викисловаре всё подробно расписали: Улепётывать значит спешить <- тараторить <- лепетать. Такая вот цепочка словообразования.

Везёт вам: Можно хорошие вопросы задавать. Мне почему-то не позволяют.

Comment: Кто может не позволить задать Вам хороший вопрос? Да вообще любой. Объясните проблему, где сможете. Лучше всего тут, просто задайте вопрос, почему "не позволяют". http://meta.rus.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @behemothus Потому что издеваются вместо ответов. А когда их осаживаешь, показываешь несостоят. их ответов, тебя называют троллем и банят. На лингв. площадках это почему-то происх. особ. часто. Я как-то задал вопрос про связь ведать - вести, дав ссылку на etymology.com где говорилось что видеть идёт от санскр. veda (знать). Мне сказали что вопрос полная ерунда, что недопустимо путать санскрит с индоевроп. и углубились только по одному из слов, что якобы доказ. что слова не связаны. Сейчас видимо срок бана вышел но это не надо долго. Но с таким подходом это не на долго и в meta делать нечего.

Comment: Ну вообще-то они правы. Но если дело только в этом, то задавайте вопрос, открыто хамить Вам никому тут не позволят, а вот насчет отношения к вопросу, то это уже, простите, надо терпеть разные мнения, если хотите не доказать, а разобраться.Впрочем обычно ругают не за мнение, а за порочную методологию, ничего общего с научной не имеющую. Попробуйте задайте свой вопрос тут.

Comment: Тут вот еще какой момент. Викисловарь - штука не слишком авторитетная. Так что сама по себе ссылка на него доказательством служить не может. да и вообще в лингвистике нет непререкаемых авторитетов. Это не математика, где единожды доказанное не подлежит пересмотру (в тех же условиях).

Comment: Видите, я уже виноватый, вы уже стоите на стороне троллей. Я уже хамло. Даже Викисловарь зачем-то приплели, вообще не понятно. При чём тут методология и почему порочна именно моя -- не понятно. Но для защиты троллей иначе нельзя. Только кидаться какашками, предпологать грязные цели и ущербность жертвы, и аппелировать вне логики. Кстати, я заметил что у троллей методология почему-то окончательная и пересмотру не подлежит, даже если она очевидно ущербная. Вы всё равное не имеете права спорить с тем кро проявил свою добрую волю ответить вам тут.

Comment: Удивительно видеть жалобы на троллей на этом сайте от человека зарегистрированного два дня и сделавшего только один ответ. На каждом сайте Stackexchange свои сообщества пользователей, обычно непересекающиеся. По своему опыту - с троллями на всех сайтах активно борются, поэтому если вы с ними часто сталкиваетесь - возможно ваше определение "тролля" не совпадает с точкой зрения сообщества. А ваш последний комментарий иначе как безосновательными обвинениями в адрес behemothus'а и назвать нельзя.

Comment: Понятие об осовательности тоже другое. Человек который вчера родился невинен и не может разделять понятия искушённых, современных личностией. Кто ещё подменой понятий и опусканием может не утереться? Я проверил, обосрали меня на http://russian.stackexchange.com. Но тут с вашей помощью стало понятно что атмосфера ничем не отличается. Так что я не удивлён. Спасибо.